# Is set.seed consistent over different versions of R (and Ubuntu)?

Tags: r, ubuntu, random-seed

I am currently running R version 3.1.0 (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and as both my R version and my operating system is getting rather old, I plan on updating both. However, I have a lot of simulations that rely on set.seed() and I would like them to still give me the same random numbers after updating both R and my operating system.

So my question is three-fold.

1. Can I update R without changing which numbers are generated from each seed?
2. Can I do the same for my operating system?
3. If no to either 1) or 2), is there a way to change the seeds in my code in such a way that they are consistent with the olds seeds?

Comment: Random number generation is done using an algorithm. `set.seed()` passes the seed to it. Hence, it shouldn't depend on OS and R version. So, 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Cross-OS consistency: yes

If you installed R on two different operating systems without manually changing defaults or the `RProfile`, you should get the same results when using `set.seed()`.

### Consistency over versions of R: not necessarily

It used to be the case that `set.seed()` would give the same results across R versions, but that's no longer generally true thanks to a little-announced update in R 3.6.0. So you can get cross version consistency comparing results before R 3.6.0, but if you compare a post-3.6.0 use of `set.seed()` to a pre-3.6.0 use of `set.seed()`, you will get different results.

You can see that in the examples below:

#### R 3.2.0

```
> set.seed(1999)
> sample(LETTERS, 3)
[1] "T" "N" "L"
```

#### R 3.5.3

```
> set.seed(1999)
> sample(LETTERS, 3)
[1] "T" "N" "L"
```

#### R 3.6.0

```
set.seed(1999)
sample(LETTERS, 3)
[1] "D" "Z" "R"
```

The reason for the inconsistency is that in R 3.6.0, [the default kind of under-the-hood random-number generator was changed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html). Now, in order to get the results from `set.seed()` to match, you have to first call the function `RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")`.

#### R 3.6.0

```
> RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
Warning message:
In RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding") : non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
> set.seed(1999)
> sample(Letters, 3)
[1] "T" "N" "L"
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in accepted answer, the default algorithm for sampling changed from version 3.6.0 onwards:

> *sample.kind* can be "Rounding" or "Rejection", or partial matches to these. The former was the default in versions prior to 3.6.0: it made sample noticeably non-uniform on large populations, and should only be used for reproduction of old results. See PR#17494 for a discussion.

**In R versions 3.6.0 and later**, you can keep consistency by using the older algorithm in a **one liner**:

```
set.seed(<seed_number_here>, sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

Notice that `sample.kind` option was added in 3.6.0 so **you cannot use the newer, better method on older R versions** (that is, `set.seed(<seed_number_here>, sample.kind = "Rejection")` does not work in R versions prior to 3.6.0).

Answer (score 3):

Having tested on several R versions (3.1.0, 3.3.1, 3.4.2) and two different machines (Windows 7 x64, Windows 10 x64), I got the same `runif()` random numbers with the same `set.seed()` independently of the R versions and the operating system. As far as I know, this suggests a yes for both questions 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realised that this could be tested rather easily. So I ran

set.seed(75842)
rnorm(3)

On two computers, using different operative systems and different versions of R. In both cases I got
[1]  1.5704983 -0.9103801  0.6197490

So it appears that it will be safe to upgrade from that point of view.