# Same seed, different OS, different random numbers in R

Tags: r, random, operating-system, random-seed

I was experiencing inconsistent results between two machines and a linux server, until I realized that fixing the seed was having different effects. I am running different `R` versions in all of them, all above `3.3.0`. Here are the examples:

**Linux 1**

```
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] -0.4463588
> version
               _
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          3.0
year           2016
month          05
day            03
svn rev        70573
language       R
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

**Linux 2**

```
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
> version
               _
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          4.2
year           2017
month          09
day            28
svn rev        73368
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
nickname       Short Summer
```

**Mac OS**

```
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

**Windows**

```
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

Linux gives a different random number generation from the same seed, thus making the result of a script run on it not fully reproducible (depending on the OS in which they are re-run, the results will agree or not). This is annoying.

I do not know what is happening here. Particularly:

- (1) Is it an issue with `R`'s versions or something more involved?
- (2) How can this inconsistent behaviour be avoided? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** originated from @Jesse Tweedle answer (output in Linux 1 in a new session):

```
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] -0.4463588
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] -0.4463588
> set.seed(102); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.05752965
> set.seed(10, kind = "Mersenne-Twister"); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
> set.seed(10); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
> set.seed(102); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.1805229
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199415/is-set-seed-consistent-over-different-versions-of-r-and-ubuntu for someone who finds consistent random numbers using set.seed across OSes / Rs.

Comment: So you know how R was installed on linux 1? Built from source? Did it use use custom flags during compilation? If using a standard build I would expect the random numbers to be the same across all (recent) builds. I don't think this has changed in R in a long time.

Comment: @MrFlick Unfortunately I do not know how `R` was installed on Linux 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## From docs:

[Random docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html):

`RNGversion can be used to set the random generators as they were in an earlier R version (for reproducibility).`

So try this on all systems:

```
set.seed(10, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion"); rnorm(1)
[1] 0.01874617
```

Comment: So if you call `RNGkind()` on "Linux 1" it says `[1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"`? 

Comment: This! I still do not know what was happening exactly, but this does the trick. (I edit the question for proper format). To your comment: yes it does.

Comment: Ok, great. I forgot to add `normal.kind` argument at first (since you're generating random normals, and the second argument is specifically for normals). 

Comment: @epsilone Please see the answer here for an explanation of why the two Linux results differ. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381613/5373794