# Counting the number of specific integers per column in an R matrix

Tags: r, matrix, count, apply

I have a matrix (10 x 100) where I need to count the number of each integer per column so I have a final matrix that is (3 x 100). Counts for 0, 1, and 2 per column.

I think the apply function will be useful here, the code I provided is a solution I envision.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
a <- matrix(sample(0:2, size=100, replace=TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=100)
out <- apply(a, 2, function(x) count(x))

 Desired output: rows are the sum of each variable "0, 1, 2"

   1 2 3 ...  n
 0 1 1 3
 1 6 3 3
 2 3 6 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function called `table` that counts the distinct values of the whole object. You can apply it to each column, i.e.

```
apply(a, 2, table)
```

to include NAs in the count just use the option `useNA`, i.e.

```
apply(a, 2, table, useNA = 'always')

#or with complete syntax
apply(a, 2, function(i)table(i, useNA = 'always'))
```

As @IceCreamToucan mentions in comments, If you have missing values in any column, then you want be able to coerce to to a data frame (or matrix for that matter). To overcome this, we can convert each column to factor with `levels = c(0:2)`, i.e.

```
apply(a, 2, function(i) table(factor(i, levels = c(0:2)), useNA = 'always'))
```

Comment: My actual matrix is huge (100 x 3,000,000) and it contains NA's in some of the rows. Table has a feature called useNA but I am having trouble using it properly, do you have any advice? as <- as.data.table(apply(a, 2, table(useNA="always")))
Error in table(useNA = "always") : nothing to tabulate

Comment: You just made a syntax mistake. Try `apply(a, 2, table, useNA = 'always')`

Comment: If some columns don't contain all three integers, attempting to make this a data.frame with `as.data.frame(apply(a, 2, table))` will result in `Error ... arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2` (or 3, 1 depending on the number of integers present)

Comment: What do you mean? What would be a case?

Comment: This example is such a case. Some columns don't have all three integers, so the table only has two elements for that column, and `as.data.frame` produces an error. If you're using `as.data.table` you get a warning and it recycles the short outputs.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Edited. Give it a try now

Comment: Yep, that works as expected. I'm guessing I ran into the [R version set.seed difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199415/is-set-seed-consistent-over-different-versions-of-r-and-ubuntu) wrt this example. Time to finally upgrade this machine I guess.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan ahhh...makes sense. I had no idea such case existed

Answer (score 1):

This produces a data.frame and ensures that for each input column the output column includes all three integers (even if the input column does not). Note: `colSums` also has a `na.rm` argument.

```
data.frame(
  int_counted = 0:2, 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(0:2, function(x) colSums(a == x)))
)
```

Output

```
#   int_counted X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
# 1           0  4  2  2  2  3  8  1  2  3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4   2
# 2           1  5  4  4  3  2  2  6  4  3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4
# 3           2  1  4  4  5  5  0  3  4  4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1   4
#   X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30 X31 X32 X33 X34 X35 X36 X37 X38 X39 X40 X41 X42 X43 X44 X45
# 1   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4   2   2   2   3
# 2   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4   4   3   2
# 3   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1   4   4   5   5
#   X46 X47 X48 X49 X50 X51 X52 X53 X54 X55 X56 X57 X58 X59 X60 X61 X62 X63 X64 X65 X66 X67 X68
# 1   8   1   2   3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2
# 2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4
# 3   0   3   4   4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4
#   X69 X70 X71 X72 X73 X74 X75 X76 X77 X78 X79 X80 X81 X82 X83 X84 X85 X86 X87 X88 X89 X90 X91
# 1   3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3   3   4
# 2   3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3   4   5
# 3   4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4   3   1
#   X92 X93 X94 X95 X96 X97 X98 X99 X100
# 1   2   2   2   3   8   1   2   3    3
# 2   4   4   3   2   2   6   4   3    4
# 3   4   4   5   5   0   3   4   4    3
```