# Cluster contains no observations

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, mclust

I implemented a Cluster Solution in production with Mclust / GMM. The algorithm is running on initial data and the solution will be applied on unseen data (predict.Mclust).
It worked fine and now it gives me a different solution when I run the function with the same seed to the same data. There are clusters with no observations in it. How can this happen? I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance. If you need further details please let me know

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the change in the `sample()` function from R-3.6 on. See this post:
[1]: [Is set.seed consistent over different versions of R (and Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199415/is-set-seed-consistent-over-different-versions-of-r-and-ubuntu/56381613#56381613)

After Version R-3.6, to get the same results, use a call to this function before setting your seed: `RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")`

Thank you @ Luca Scrucca for your support