# From a pairwise matrix, find the largest group of individuals that equal a certain value

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, igraph, submatrix

I have a pairwise relatedness 39x39 matrix containing the relatedness values for all pairwise combinations of 39 individuals. I would like to find the largest group of individuals that are completely unrelated, i.e. where all pairwise relatedness values i the group equal 0.

Is there an easy way to do this in R?

A simpler example:

```
set.seed(420)

#Create the matrix
relatedness.matrix <- matrix(data = sample(x = c(0.5, 1, 0,0), size = 25, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

# Matrix has the same upper and lower triangles
relatedness.matrix[upper.tri(relatedness.matrix)] <- relatedness.matrix[lower.tri(relatedness.matrix)]

# Add names for simplicity of reference
colnames(relatedness.matrix) <- letters[1:5]
rownames(relatedness.matrix) <- letters[1:5]

# Relatedness between the same individual does not count
diag(relatedness.matrix) <- NA
```

In this case there are three possible solutions: a 2x2 matrix with only `e` and `b`, a 2x2 matrix with only `c` and `d`, and a 2x2 matrix with only `a` and `e`. Adding any other individuals to any of those matrices would be adding a related individual.

EDIT: added that upper and lower triangles are the same, and that there's actually multiple 2x2 solutions in this example.

Comment: The seed will be different on different machines; your columns `e` and `b` will be different than mine. You should write out your example matrix or save the matrix on your machine using `dput()` and paste that output here. Otherwise we do not know what you want.

Comment: @mikebader the seed will **not be different on different machines**. `set.seed` and sharing code is a fine way to share data reproducibly. (There are some edge cases, like if you've changed your default RNG or are using a very old version of R, it may not work in every single case, but `set.seed` is generally quite reliable.)

Comment: Oh, good to know! Your comment prompted a search, and there may be differences by version (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199415/is-set-seed-consistent-over-different-versions-of-r-and-ubuntu). I'm confused because I don't see a pattern when I run the code that resembles what OP wants.

Comment: @mikebader I thought `set.seed` would work. I realized though that i did leave off that the matrix has the same upper and lower triangles. I'll fix that in the original post.

Comment: Are you looking for a set of dyads (pairs) where the matrix value between row and column equals zero?

Comment: I think the solution is non-trivial. A keyword is "maximum size square submatrix", e.g., here: https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/maximum-size-square-sub-matrix

Comment: @mikebader No, I'm looking for the largest group where all the values between all the rows and columns equals 0.

Comment: Your question isn't clear by what you mean by "group." The examples you provided only describe dyads (since they are all 2x2 from a symmetrical matrix).

Comment: @AlexKrohn: What helps (I think) is the symmetry of your matrix. So there might be a simpler approach than the general ones.

Comment: @AlexKrohn To make the matrix symmetric, it would be `relatedness.matrix[lower.tri(relatedness.matrix)] <- t(relatedness.matrix)[lower.tri(relatedness.matrix)]`

Comment: @mikebader yes, there was a change in the discrete uniform RNG in R 3.6.0. So some functions (like `sample` as in this question) will give different results based on the seed between versions prior < 3.6.0 and versions >= 3.6.0. There are probably other edge cases too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set of unrelated individuals in a symmetric adjacency matrix describes an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)). We can use `igraph::largest_ivs` to find the largest such sets.

I'll use a larger matrix that is actually symmetric.

```
set.seed(420)

m <- matrix(sample(0:2, 26^2, 1), 26, 26, 0, rep(list(letters), 2))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- NA
```

Check that the matrix is symmetric

```
isSymmetric(m)
#> [1] TRUE

m
#>    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
#> a NA  0  1  2  1  2  0  2  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  2  1  1
#> b  0 NA  0  1  2  2  0  2  0  2  0  2  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  0  1  2  1  2  0  1
#> c  1  0 NA  0  1  0  2  1  2  1  0  1  0  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  2  0  2  0  1  0
#> d  2  1  0 NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  0  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  1  0  1  0  2  1
#> e  1  2  1  2 NA  2  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  2  0  2  0  2  2  1  2  1  2  2
#> f  2  2  0  2  2 NA  2  2  2  1  1  2  1  2  0  2  0  2  2  0  1  1  0  2  2  2
#> g  0  0  2  2  1  2 NA  0  2  1  2  2  2  2  0  1  2  0  2  1  0  0  1  1  2  1
#> h  2  2  1  2  0  2  0 NA  2  2  1  0  2  2  1  0  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  2
#> i  2  0  2  2  1  2  2  2 NA  1  2  1  0  2  2  0  2  2  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  2
#> j  0  2  1  2  0  1  1  2  1 NA  1  1  2  2  0  0  1  1  2  2  2  1  0  0  2  2
#> k  1  0  0  1  1  1  2  1  2  1 NA  2  2  1  0  0  2  0  2  0  0  1  1  1  1  2
#> l  2  2  1  1  0  2  2  0  1  1  2 NA  1  1  2  0  2  2  1  2  1  0  0  2  1  1
#> m  0  2  0  0  0  1  2  2  0  2  2  1 NA  0  2  2  0  2  1  1  1  1  0  2  1  1
#> n  1  2  1  1  0  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  0 NA  1  0  1  2  1  2  0  1  0  1  1  2
#> o  2  1  2  2  1  0  0  1  2  0  0  2  2  1 NA  2  2  0  1  2  1  2  2  1  1  0
#> p  2  2  2  1  2  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  2 NA  2  2  2  1  0  2  0  0  1  2
#> q  0  2  2  2  0  0  2  1  2  1  2  2  0  1  2  2 NA  1  0  1  2  2  1  0  1  1
#> r  0  1  2  2  2  2  0  1  2  1  0  2  2  2  0  2  1 NA  1  1  2  1  2  2  2  1
#> s  0  1  1  1  0  2  2  1  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  0  1 NA  2  1  1  2  1  1  1
#> t  0  0  2  2  2  0  1  1  0  2  0  2  1  2  2  1  1  1  2 NA  0  0  1  2  2  0
#> u  0  1  2  1  2  1  0  2  2  2  0  1  1  0  1  0  2  2  1  0 NA  2  2  0  2  0
#> v  2  2  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  2  2  2  1  1  0  2 NA  2  0  1  1
#> w  2  1  2  1  2  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  1  2  2  1  2  2 NA  0  2  0
#> x  2  2  0  0  1  2  1  1  0  0  1  2  2  1  1  0  0  2  1  2  0  0  0 NA  1  2
#> y  1  0  1  2  2  2  2  1  0  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  1 NA  0
#> z  1  1  0  1  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  2  0  2  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  2  0 NA
```

Get the largest independent sets:

```
library(igraph)

is <- largest_ivs(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected"))
is
#> [[1]]
#> + 4/26 vertices, named, from 272900e:
#> [1] i p w x
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> + 4/26 vertices, named, from 272900e:
#> [1] c d v x
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> + 4/26 vertices, named, from 272900e:
#> [1] j p w x
```

Verify that no edges exist among the independent sets.

```
lapply(is, \(i) m[i, i])
#> [[1]]
#>    i  p  w  x
#> i NA  0  0  0
#> p  0 NA  0  0
#> w  0  0 NA  0
#> x  0  0  0 NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    c  d  v  x
#> c NA  0  0  0
#> d  0 NA  0  0
#> v  0  0 NA  0
#> x  0  0  0 NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    j  p  w  x
#> j NA  0  0  0
#> p  0 NA  0  0
#> w  0  0 NA  0
#> x  0  0  0 NA
```

---

As a side note, the independent sets in a graph formed from an adjacency matrix, `m`, will be the same as the cliques in the graph formed by `!m`. Interestingly, for my small example, `largest_cliques` is more performant than `largest_ivs` for finding the desired answer:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cliques = largest_cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(!m, "undirected")),
  ivs = largest_ivs(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected"))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#>  cliques 319.7 348.6 372.581 368.90 388.55  555.0   100
#>      ivs 560.8 589.6 629.992 616.55 654.35 1187.6   100
```

And the performance difference grows as the matrix gets larger:

```
m <- matrix(sample(0:2, 1e4, 1), 100, 100, 0)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- NA

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cliques = largest_cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(!m, "undirected")),
  ivs = largest_ivs(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected"))
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  cliques   2.5735   2.7651   3.275977   2.9013   3.3138   7.9742   100
#>      ivs 161.9572 182.3812 191.595736 191.2344 202.1377 243.5654   100

m <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4e4, 1), 200, 200, 0)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- NA

system.time(cl <- largest_cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(!m, "undirected")))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.05    0.00    0.05
system.time(is <- largest_ivs(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected")))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   10.14    0.00   10.15
```

Check that the answers are the same.

```
library(data.table)

identical(
  setorder(as.data.table(t(mapply(sort, cl)))),
  setorder(as.data.table(t(mapply(sort, is))))
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Brilliant interpretation of the problem and solve it with `igraph`, +1!

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`igraph` solutions by @jblood94](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77107622/12158757) is the most efficient and concise way to interpret and solve the ***independent set*** problem.

---

If you would like to take it as a coding practice (with a lot of fun), you can also try to solve the problem with base R **only**, which might be less performant but can work properly. Below is an example

```
f <- function(m) {
    helper <- function(mat, S, x) {
        if (all(mat[cbind(S, x)] == 0)) {
            c(S, x)
        }
    }

    nms <- colnames(m)
    v <- unique(sort(c(which((m == 0) * lower.tri(m) == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))))
    lst <- as.list(v)
    repeat {
        lstn <- unlist(
            lapply(
                lst,
                \(x) {
                    Filter(
                        length,
                        lapply(
                            v[v > max(x)],
                            \(z) helper(m, x, z)
                        )
                    )
                }
            ),
            recursive = FALSE
        )
        if (length(lstn) == 0) {
            return(lapply(lst, \(k) nms[k]))
        } else {
            lst <- lstn
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
> f(m)
[[1]]
[1] "c" "d" "v" "x"

[[2]]
[1] "i" "p" "w" "x"

[[3]]
[1] "j" "p" "w" "x"
```

## data

Borrowed the same data from [@jblood94](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77107622/12158757)

```
set.seed(420)
m <- matrix(sample(0:2, 26^2, 1), 26, 26, 0, rep(list(letters), 2))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- NA
```